# ReactNative AsyncStorage updating state or which lifecycle will execute

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

i am setting up state based on value from AsyncStorage. Example:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    this.setState({ token });
 }
```

Now i want the state to get updated whenever token is updated (by other component or due to timeout). I tried putting the logic in componentWillReceiveProps but did not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can not trigger methods when the AsyncStorage is updated. If you want to have reactivity, you should use something like [Redux](http://redux.js.org).

Comment: You might want to try remove the previous token and then set the new one, instead of updating it.